# Selenium Webdriver and javascript

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I get the value of this Tried this , But go an error 
" Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
    at canvasdrag.Canvas.main(Canvas.java:57)
 "

```
    WebElement hello = (WebElement)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return window.app.design.DOOR.length");
String world =  hello.getText();
    System.out.println(world);
```

Comment: What are trying to achieve? You are trying to convert `Long` to `WebElement`. Java script you have written will return `Long` which you are converting to `WebElement'.

Comment: Please add some context to this question. Not able to understand what you are trying to achieve

Comment: I'm trying to fetch a a javascript element as a text . I'll be more clear, I have a html 5 canvas i open the console in crome browser, there I type in window.app.design.DOOR and hit enter I get the output as "8" can I get the same in my eclipse console ? Are these detials enough ? do you want me to explain more?

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript you execute returns a number but you are trying to treat this number as a `WebElement` object. It's not clear what you were trying to do exactly but it would be either:

```
long hello = (Long)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return window.app.design.DOOR.length");
System.out.println(world);
```

or:

```
WebElement hello = (WebElement)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript(
    "return [something which resolves to a DOM element]");
String world =  hello.getText();
System.out.println(world);
```

I don't know what element you might be looking for so you'll have to replace `[something which resolves to a DOM element]` with whatever you actually need.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
 at canvasdrag.Canvas.main(Canvas.java:57). I get this error now